# getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() and getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated from Android Q

Tags: android, android-10.0

How to get external directory file path and store file at external public directory in Android Q.

I have used two methods for getting public directory but from android Q it depcrecated now, which way we can store into external directory.

```
 1. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
 2. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

Replacement :-

```
 1. context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

It is returning private directory for storing but it will not accessible to public directory.

Comment: You no longer have direct filesystem access to public directories on external storage and removable storage. Use the Storage Access Framework (`ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, etc.). If your content happens to be media, use `MediaStore`.

Comment: Can you please provide answer on how to store file using MediaStore?

Comment: [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.5/ConferenceVideos) allows the user to download some of my conference videos. I use `MediaStore` to store those videos, with separate code for Android 10+ and older devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please answer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58408949/how-to-check-directory-is-exists-or-not-in-android-q

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please check this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433728/write-external-storage-permission-is-not-required-in-androidq-with-target-api-le