# WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not required in AndroidQ with target API level 29, does it breaks security?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0

I have stored image file into External Directory through Media store but it doesn't required permission for AndroidQ, even i have not mention permission in manifest.

```
compileSdkVersion 29

defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
    }
```

**Note: Any application can store files on external storage without requesting permission to user, so is it break down security violation?**

Comment: Thats very weird, might be bug, I know on androidQ you have to use scoped storage, maybe there is a bug somewhere

Comment: have you tried building a release apk and using it on a phone without developer options on?

Comment: Can you put some code elaborating how actually did you write a file ? And by "external" do you mean Private external or Public external ?

Comment: I'm storing file by use of media store which is part or scoped storage.

Comment: @Maan I'm writing file as an public which is visible to every application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app that uses scoped storage always has read/write access to the files that it creates, both inside and outside its app-specific directory. As a result, if your app saves and accesses only the files that it creates, you don't need to request the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

For more information - [[here]](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped)

Answer (score 2):

The argument, as I understand it, is that with `MediaStore` you are only supposed to be able to write to a few locations, based on the media type. `MediaStore` is supposed to be validating that your request seems legitimate.

However, somebody (perhaps you?) suggested that `IS_RELATIVE` allows writing in arbitrary locations. If that were the case, then I would be much more concerned.

Comment: Do you mean for any Environment.{directory} it is not required permission for storage?

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ: You are not using `Environment`. You are using `MediaStore`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any reference to the official document ?

Comment: @BuffK: The official document for... what?

Comment: @CommonsWare Which location does MediaStore supported, and which media type(mp3, m4a, flac ..) will be supported? How to find that list? Thank you.

Comment: @BuffK: Oh, I really wish that was documented, particularly the media type aspect. I am not aware of any official documentation. I based my comments on experiments that I have run to see what seems to work (and seems not to work).